# Adding a constant to all elements of a matrix and solving

Tags: linear-algebra, matrices, systems-of-equations, problem-solving, matrix-equations

Will solving
$$\begin{pmatrix}
1 & 1 & 1 & 1 & 1\\
-1 & 0 & 1 & 2 & 3 \\
1 & 0 & 1 & 4 & 9 \\
-1 & 0 & 1 & 8 & 27 \\
1 & 0 & 1 & 16 & 81 \\
\end{pmatrix}
\begin{pmatrix}
w_1 \\
w_2 \\
w_3 \\
w_4 \\
w_5 \\
\end{pmatrix}
=
\begin{pmatrix}
0 \\
1 \\
0 \\
0 \\
0 \\
\end{pmatrix},
$$
produce the same values for $w_i$ as solving for
$$\begin{pmatrix}
1+a & 1+a & 1+a & 1+a & 1+a\\
-1+a & 0+a & 1+a & 2+a & 3+a \\
1+a & 0+a & 1+a & 4+a & 9+a \\
-1+a & 0+a & 1+a & 8+a & 27+a \\
1+a & 0+a & 1+a & 16+a & 81+a \\
\end{pmatrix}
\begin{pmatrix}
w_1 \\
w_2 \\
w_3 \\
w_4 \\
w_5 \\
\end{pmatrix}
=
\begin{pmatrix}
0 \\
1 \\
0 \\
0 \\
0 \\
\end{pmatrix}?$$
And if so, by which law of matrices ? Thank you.

Answer (score 2, accepted):

This happens to be true for the particular matrix and vector that are given.  Define the following matrix and vectors:
$$
M = \pmatrix{1 & 1 & 1 & 1 & 1\\
-1 & 0 & 1 & 2 & 3 \\
1 & 0 & 1 & 4 & 9 \\
-1 & 0 & 1 & 8 & 27 \\
1 & 0 & 1 & 16 & 81}, \quad
e = \pmatrix{1\\1\\1\\1\\1}, \quad 
e_2 = \pmatrix{0\\1\\0\\0\\0}, \quad 
w = \pmatrix{w_1\\w_2\\w_3\\w_4\\w_5}.
$$
We are given that $Mw = e_2$. The first entry of $Mw$ is equal to the product $e^Tw$, so from $Mw = e_2$ we see that it must hold that $e^Tw = 0$.

The new equation that you present can be written as
$$
(M + a ee^T)w = e_2.
$$
We can see that this equation must hold because
$$
(M + aee^T)w = Mw + aee^Tw = Mw + ae(e^Tw) = Mw + 0 = Mw = e_2.
$$